Web Animation API: the Promise of animation.finished is always pending
after using animation.cancel(), the Promise of animation.finished is always pending, then I cant use Promise to wait the animation fulfilled.
I tried using every methods I can, such as animation.finish(), but it is still pending.


let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let element = null;
let currentId = 1;
let ani = null;
let transformArray = [
  {transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)'},
  {transform: 'translate(100px, 0px)'}
];


btn.onclick = function () {
  element = document.querySelector("#icon" + currentId);
  Promise.all([ani && ani.finished]).then(function() {
    ani = element && element.animate(transformArray, {
      duration: 1000,
      fill: "forwards",
      easing: "ease"
    })

    ani.finished.then(() => {
      ani.cancel()
    });
  });
  currentId++;
  if (currentId == 4) {
    currentId = 1
  }
}
.query-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#icon1 {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
#icon2 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
#icon3 {
    background-color: orangered;
}
<div class="query-icon" id="icon1">
</div>
<div class="query-icon" id="icon2">
</div>
<div class="query-icon" id="icon3">
</div>


<button id="btn">animate</button>



What I expect is that everytime I click the button, the box cancels its animation when last animation finished, and change into another box to animate.

Please post the relevant code and describe what you expect to happen with that code and what really happens.

Why do you even wait for finished? Here you are waiting for the previous animation has finished before calling its cancel() method, which won't do much since the animation is already over. It's not entirely clear what you want but if it's to stop the running animation when starting a new one, then you just need to call the potentially set ani?.cancel() at the beginning of the event handler: https://jsfiddle.net/h1f54d0r/ If it's another behavior you're after, please clarify your question.

Thanks a lot, it works, however I am still confused about why it keeps pending status after calling cancel() method...



let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let element = null;
let currentId = 1;
let ani = null;
let transformArray = [
  {transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)'},
  {transform: 'translate(100px, 0px)'}
];


btn.onclick = function () {
  element = document.querySelector("#icon" + currentId);
  Promise.all([ani && ani.finished]).then(function() {
    ani = element && element.animate(transformArray, {
      duration: 1000,
      fill: "forwards",
      easing: "ease"
    })

    ani.finished.then(() => {
      ani.cancel()
    });
  });
  currentId++;
  if (currentId == 4) {
    currentId = 1
  }
}
.query-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#icon1 {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
#icon2 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
#icon3 {
    background-color: orangered;
}
<div class="query-icon" id="icon1">
</div>
<div class="query-icon" id="icon2">
</div>
<div class="query-icon" id="icon3">
</div>


<button id="btn">animate</button>





let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let element = null;
let currentId = 1;
let ani = null;
let transformArray = [
  {transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)'},
  {transform: 'translate(100px, 0px)'}
];


btn.onclick = function () {
  element = document.querySelector("#icon" + currentId);
  Promise.all([ani && ani.finished]).then(function() {
    ani = element && element.animate(transformArray, {
      duration: 1000,
      fill: "forwards",
      easing: "ease"
    })

    ani.finished.then(() => {
      ani.cancel()
    });
  });
  currentId++;
  if (currentId == 4) {
    currentId = 1
  }
}
.query-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#icon1 {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
#icon2 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
#icon3 {
    background-color: orangered;
}
<div class="query-icon" id="icon1">
</div>
<div class="query-icon" id="icon2">
</div>
<div class="query-icon" id="icon3">
</div>


<button id="btn">animate</button>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
